# How to add tables or attach styles in angular-editor?

Tags: angular, richtextbox

Am using angular-editor in my ng15. It supports all basic features except a table, When data is copied from Excel, it renders simple format, while inspecting it, I could see border 0.

[image]
[image]

It's good to attach styles So that when sent to mail, It renders a correct Table.

Thanks